# Hiding/Closing form is not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have `login` form and `agent` form in my application. The first scenario of my application is when the user login successfully all the credentials(`server , username, password, status`) will be save in text file and I already finish it.
My second scenario is when the user close the `agent` form and open the application again, the application will read all the credential in text file and will be login automatically and I already finish it but my problem is when I open the application both form show the `login` and `agent` form where the expected result is only the `agent` form will display.

[image: Result of Form]

Here is my code for login form:

```
private void login_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class.loginFunction logs = new Class.loginFunction();

            string isLogged, user, pass, server;
            try
            {

                isLogged = logs.readConfigFile(4);
                user = logs.readConfigFile(2);
                pass = logs.readConfigFile(3);
                server = logs.readConfigFile(1);

                if (isLogged.Equals("1"))
                {
                    logs.loginAuthentication(user, pass);
                }
                else
                {
                    txtServer.Text = server;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Thrown: " + ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Here is the code for the method of login:

```
public void loginAuthentication(string agentId, string pass)
        {
            login idx = new login();
            WebServiceInfo webInfo = new WebServiceInfo();
            LoginInfo logInfo = new LoginInfo();
            eDataNewUi eNewUi = new eDataNewUi();
            try
            {
                logInfo.serverAddress = readConfigFile(1);
                webInfo.url = "http://" + logInfo.serverAddress + "/eDataTran/service/main/agentLogin"; // store Url Of service in string
                webInfo.jsonData = "{\"agentId\":\"" + agentId + "\" ,\"password\":\"" + pass + "\"}";

                // Convert our JSON in into bytes using ascii encoding
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(webInfo.jsonData);

                //  HttpWebRequest 
                HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webInfo.url);
                webrequest.Method = "POST";
                webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

                //  Get stream data out of webrequest object
                Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                newStream.Close();

                //  Declare & read the response from service
                HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

                // Fetch the response from the POST web service
                Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
                string result = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
                loResponseStream.Close();

                JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);
                string responseCode = o["Data"][0]["ResponseCode"].ToString(); 

                switch (responseCode)
                {
                    case "0":
                        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is not valid");
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        idx.Hide(); // this part where the form is not hiding
                        eNewUi.Show();
                        eNewUi.tssUserId.Text = "User Id: " + agentId;
                        getAgentId(agentId);
                        break;
                }

                webresponse.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Response: " + ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Here is my program.cs

```
 static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "oreilly.com OneAtATimeDemo");
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application is running already!");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new login());
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }  

        }
```

Comment: If I understood the scenarios correctly, when you open the `Agent` form it should check the saved TextFile generated from the `Login` form?

Comment: You could implement a method in your static class `Program` that checks if the certain Textfile exists.

Comment: @Hexxed When you open the application the first form will show is the `login` so i put my code in the `login_load` event then it will check the generated textfile and after that it will direct to `agent` form

Comment: @Hexxed you are saying that i should add my code in static class `Program` instead in `login_load` event

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the presented code. Im saying that you could add a checking method in your `Program.cs`. See my answer below.

Comment: You're saving user credentials in a plain text file?????  That sounds scary.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Nope. I use AES for its encryption

Answer (score 2):

As per info of the scenarios, you would be needing to check if the Textfile is generated. You should add a checking method on your `Program.cs` if this TextFile was generated else your application would fire the `LoginFrm`

Sample Code:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if(TextFileChecker())
        {
             Application.Run(new AgentFrm());
        }
        else
        {
             Application.Run(new LoginFrm());
        }
    }

        private bool TextFileChecker()
        {
             //run a checking method for the textfile
        }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because of no explaination.  *Try this* doesn't help the OP nor future readers understand why this might work vs the original code.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Added explanation, my apologies.

Comment: @Hexxed i try your solution but it throws me an error `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.`

Comment: @SherwinObciana Are you using reflection to laod assembly

Comment: @SherwinObciana I cant make further investigation. I havent seen your code. Its just a sample code. Im suspecting you ran an `Application.Run()` method before running the `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` if thats the error message

Comment: @SherwinObciana I have tried your `Program.cs` Im not getting any errors. There must be something in your underlying code.

Comment: @Hexxed Thank you for your answer. I get some idea on what should i do and it is now working but i dont know if its the best solution for me

Comment: @SherwinObciana You should consider other way of authentications/sessions because storing it in a Textfile then encrypting it is dangerous practice. It will be another question of its own.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned anything about the `Program.cs` but I have seen some similar problems so I will just assume the contents is similar to the following

```
 private static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }
```

Application already creates a `Login` object for you and in method `loginAuthentication`

```
public void loginAuthentication(string agentId, string pass){
    login idx = new login();//Here you created another Login object
....
}
```

As far as I am concerned your program successfully comes to case "1":

```
switch (responseCode) {
    case "0":
        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is not valid");
        break;
    case "1":
        //This is the part where you are trying to hide a form, which is not even shown         
        idx.Hide();
```

Suggested Main:

```
private static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var hasCredentialFile = CheckCredentialFile();        
    Application.Run(hasCredentialFile ? new Agent():Login());
}
```

Comment: Yes it comes to case `1` but the form didnt hide even  i try this code `login idx = (login)Application.OpenForms["login"];`

Comment: @SherwinObciana  You have to prevent the Application class from making the form visible. You cannot tinker with Application, that's locked up. What I would suggest is change the logic in your `Main`

Comment: it throws me an error `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.`

Comment: @SherwinObciana Are you using reflection to load assemblies?

Comment: @SherwinObciana Moreover, If you are creating a form instance do it after `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);`